# How to call a js function when an element with a particular class is hovered?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a function when an element of a particular class is hovered. Suppose there are 100 div and 50 of them have class test, so what I wanted was that a function should be called when I hover on the divs with class test.

```
<div class="test" mouseover="myfunc()">
</div>
<div class="test" mouseover="myfunc()">
</div>
<div class="test" mouseover="myfunc()">
</div>
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfucn(){......}
</script>
```

but this becomes too tedious, so what I want is a generalized method  which targets all test class elements without needing to write mouseover event again and again. I prefer only javascript(because I was learning it) but have no problems with jquery.

Comment: A concrete workingexample would be nice to help you!

Comment: would be good if you can show whatever you have tried till now. and also do you need the solution in javascript only or jQuery is also fine

Comment: sure I will edit the question.

Comment: not an example but a mock up of the problem you are facing while trying to do this and would be better if show what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mine using only Javascript.
Try using Jquery like this.

```
function doSomeThing(){
     //do something
}

$("div.test").hover(function(){
     doSomeThing();
});
```

if you want only Javascript try this:

```
function doSomeThing(){
    //do something
}

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for (i in el){
    el[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        //do something here

        //or call a function
        doSomeThing();
    });
}
```

More information

When you do `document.getElementsByClassName("test");`

You will get it as an `Array`. Then you have to add them an `addEventListener("mouseover")` to make them know when they were hovered.
After that, you write something you want to do inside its function.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but can you show how to do  the same in javascript.

Comment: @TubbyStubby I added Javascript under my Jquery code

Comment: So the for loop is checking all elements with that class  whether it is being hovered or not. thanks for answer.

Comment: @TubbyStubby for..loop is using for give each element an event listener.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- get all of the elements (e.g. with `getElementsByClassName`) and then bind an event handler to each of them (with `addEventListener`) *or*
- bind an event handler to an ancestor of those elements and then, each time the event fires, check the `target` property of the event object (which is the first argument to the event handler function) to see if it is an element with the class you care about

Comment: after getting all the elements with `getElementsByClassName` how to check whether anyone is hovered or not.

Comment: @TubbyStubby — You loop over them and add mouseover and mouseout event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

This method makes use of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

```
$('.myClass').hover(function () {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in vanilla JS instead of jQuery here is a basic example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('YOUR_CLASS')
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    console.log('Element', event.target, 'is hovered')
  })
}
```

Here you basically select all elements that have "YOUR_CLASS" class and bind an function to mouseover event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hover function from jQuery : https://api.jquery.com/hover/

For example :

```
 $( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);`
```

This example adds class hover when hover in - and removes the class when hover out

Answer (score 0):

```
$("test").hover(
    function(event) {
    // The mouse has entered the element
    },
    function (event) {
    // The mouse has left the element
    }
 );
```

If you used JQuery, code should be something like above

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple workaround:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".your_class").forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {doSomeFunction();})
    elem.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {secondFunction();})
});
```